# Why is this generating a mismatched-input error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, rules

I am currently trying to build my first rule with Drools 7.0.0 following a simple tutorial in springboot. However, I am stuck at the first step of my rule building, it just won't instantiate my KieModule.java because of an error in my .drl file (where my only rule is defined)!

Here's my Bean definition (It breaks at the .buildAll() method) :

```
  /**
   * Used by the Drools engine.
   * 
   * @return KieContainer used by Drools.
   */
  @Bean
  @DependsOn({"kStreamJson"})
  public KieContainer kieContainer() {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(drlFile));
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();

    return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
  }
```

Here is my .drl file (source of the problem) :

```
package com.ruleengine;

import com.ruleengine.domain.Alert;
import com.unifiedformat.UnifiedData;
import java.util.*;

global com.ruleengine.domain.Alert alert;
dialect  "mvel"

function Double getMae(UnifiedData unifiedData) { 
    return Double.valueOf(unifiedData.getData().getValue());
}

rule "Check MAE - Scenario 1"
    when
        mae:Double(getMae(UnifiedData(getData().getValue()) > 0.1);
    then
        alert.setAlertMessage("ok");
end
```

And here is the error that I get :

```
2020-01-23 10:53:16.098 ERROR 3544 --- [           main] o.d.c.k.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule   : Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase
[18,8]: [ERR 102] Line 18:8 mismatched input 'alert' in rule "Check MAE - Scenario 1"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
```

I tried everything I could think of and I'm not an expert with Drools. Whatever String I put instead of the alert will make it break. Even System.out.println() doesn't work and produces a mismatched input error. Why is my rule invalid? I have no clue. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the package name.

By removing the package name of my .drl file, there was no more mismatched-input error.

I don't know why the error message from Drools wasn't about the package name, but about a fake mismatched-input.

Also, I upgraded my Drools version from 7.0.0 to 7.31